# How do you get the iteration's data from TestContext in data driven tests?

Tags: mstest, data-driven-tests

How can I get the data from a row in the current running test?
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454904/how-do-you-get-the-iteration-line-number-from-testcontext-in-data-driven-tests) answers how to get the iteration number ie 0,1,2.. of the running test:

```
int currentIteration = TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows.IndexOf(TestContext.DataRow);
```

However, I would like to get the actual data in this row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler than I expected. this is for a single column table, so the ItemArray will always be 0:

```
string currentIterationData = TestContext.DataRow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```